# How to achieve clone add functionlity with validation using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins

I need jquery stuff which allow to achieve below functionlity:

1) on click of "button", it should allow to add new(clone) row elements (as shown in below HTML).

2) In row element, it contains, SELECT LIST which has binded CHANGE event as on selection change of one dropdown, populating another dropdown.

3) also,  there are validations for text box which trigger on click of submit button. so, that is also based on textbox ID selector.

I am not able to achieve above functionlities specifically for point #2 and #3.

Please guide me.

```
      <a href="#" class="show_hide1" style="text-decoration: none; color: inherit; float: right;">
       &nbsp;</a>
  <h1 class="infoTitle clearfix">
    Other Class Information</h1>
  <br />
 <div id="hsOther" class="piTable slidingDiv1">
<div class="content1">
    <table class="divclass" width="100%">
        <tr class="tdStyle">
            <td>
                <label class="customFont" for="OtherInstitueName">
                    Class Name</label>
            </td>
            <td>
                <label class="customFont" for="OtherAddress">
                    Street Address</label>
            </td>
            <td>
                <label class="customFont" for="OtherCity">
                    City</label>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="tdStyle">
            <td class="tdStyle">
               <select data-val="true" data-val-number="The field OtherStateId must be a number."
                    data-val-required="The OtherStateId field is required." id="Select1" name="OtherStateId"
                    style="font-family: Calibri; font-size: 16px;">
                    <option value=""></option>
                    <option value="NI">NI</option>
                    <option value="UT">UT</option>
                    <option value="IO">IO</option>                       
                </select>
                <select data-val="true" data-val-number="The field OtherStateId must be a number."
                    data-val-required="The OtherStateId field is required." id="selectClass" name="OtherStateId"
                    style="font-family: Calibri; font-size: 16px;">
                    <option value=""></option>
                    <option value="NI">NI</option>
                    <option value="UT">UT</option>
                    <option value="IO">IO</option>                       
                </select>
            </td>
            <td class="tdStyle">
                <input id="OtherAddress" maxlenght="200" name="OtherAddress" style="font-family: Calibri;
                    font-size: 16px;" type="text" value="" />
            </td>
            <td class="tdStyle">
                <input id="OtherCity" maxlenght="50" name="OtherCity" style="font-family: Calibri;
                    font-size: 16px;" type="text" value="" />
            </td>
        </tr>          
       </table>
     </div>
 </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

For any newly created `Elements`, you have to attach the events handlers since by default it wont be having any.

If incase you are using clone method from jquery to clone then make sure you clone with events (by default the clone method doesnt clone the events).

Also please share the code which you have tried so far. A jsfiddle would be helpfull